# Not able to get the data from the cursor?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

```
public Cursor getsomething()
{
    this.open(); 
    Cursor c= database.query(DatabaseHandler.Table_Name,magicdata,null, null, null,null,null); 

    this.close();
    return c;
}
```

I am using this code to query my database. Then I am calling this in main activity.

```
get=X.getsomething();
if (get.getCount() > 0)
{
    if  (get.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
        String uname = get.getString(get.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
    String unknown =url + uname;
    String ax= get.getString(get.getColumnIndex("content"));
    downloadimages(url,ax); 
        }
        while (get.moveToNext());
    }
}
}}
```

I am getting an `error` here, MY code is not running and I don't know why?

error code is below

```
 02-20 10:27:18.378: E/PhonePolicy(1261): Could not preload class for phone policy com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
 02-20 10:27:18.488: D/TextLayoutCache(1261): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
 02-20 10:27:20.998: D/AndroidRuntime(1261): Shutting down VM
 02-20 10:27:20.998: W/dalvikvm(1261): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40a3e1f8)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newpicker/com.example.newpicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.newpicker/databases/content.db (conn# 0) already closed
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.newpicker/databases/content.db (conn# 0) already closed
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:413)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:400)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.example.newpicker.MainActivity.datamining(MainActivity.java:70)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at com.example.newpicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: please show us the logcat logs...

Comment: It would be more better to understand your issue if you post logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading line

> 02-20 10:27:20.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newpicker/com.example.newpicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.newpicker/databases/content.db (conn# 0) already closed

from the log we see that `database already closed` so the thing you have to do is:

Open db and make sure it is not closed until you run your cursor code:

```
    public Cursor getsomething()
    {
        // this.open(); // <-- explained below
        Cursor c= database.query(DatabaseHandler.Table_Name,magicdata,null, null, null,null,null); 

        // this.close(); // <-- if `this` refers to DB, it's a mistake, close DB at the end.
        return c;
    }
```

So at your activity code in order not to leave open your DB use something like:

```
X = new YourDatabaseClassName();  // new instance of your database (class contains getsomething method)
X.open(); // open DB
get=X.getsomething();
if (get != null && get.getCount() > 0) // also add a null check
{
    if  (get.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String uname = get.getString(get.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
            String unknown =url + uname;
            String ax= get.getString(get.getColumnIndex("content"));
            downloadimages(url,ax); 
        }
        while (get.moveToNext());
    }
    get.close(); // also close the cursor
}
X.close(); // you end with DB so close it! next time it needs to reopened
```

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) is also an android database tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. Try this.

```
String[] columnArray = { "content_id, content " };
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,columnArray, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
                String content =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            Log.i("TAG"," No value found");

        }
```